# Abstract class and methods | Ambiguity in opinions

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I just came across two distinct opinions regarding *abstract class* :

1) One says , ***abstract method cannot be used in concrete(general) class*** ; while the abstract classes can have both abstract/non-abstract methods

2) While , a tutorial that has been highly watched on youtube says , " **Any class that has an abstract method , will let its class be automatically defined as abstract** "

2nd point is totally in contrast to the 1st point ; While implementing it , I did succeed only in the 1st concept and not 2nd though . But , still I want to have a detailed clarity in this regard , if anyone can help me with patience .

Comment: *"2nd point is totally in contrast to the 1st point"* Not really. The second "opinion" just tries to say, that a class with an abstract method is "automatically" an abstract class (,but you need to manually write `abstract` to the class header). The second part (in the parenthese) is just missing.

Comment: "abstract method cannot be used in concrete(general) class" doesn't seem right. I can invoke any method from reference which allows me to do so, and only limit here is methods accessors (private...public). Methods body will come from actual instance (and abstract class can't be instantiated) so I don't see problem here or I am misunderstanding what author wanted to say. Maybe start from reading official tutorial which was created by very smart people rather than learning from youtube channel created by random person.

Comment: @peter *"and has at least one abstract method"* This is wrong. An abstract class doesn't need a single abstract method.

Comment: @Tom is correct. You can label a class as abstract when there are no abstract methods in it. I have done this in a few libraries of mine to make sure that the class is never initiated itself and MUST be inherited for better code implementation.

Comment: @Pshemo I guess it tries to say that a non-abstract method cannot contain abstract methods. And yes, that sentence is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), "If a class includes abstract methods, then the class itself must be declared abstract". It does not automatically become abstract; it needs to be marked as abstract explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Any class that contains abstract  methods cannot be instantiated because it contains methods that are undefined. Any time an object of a class is created, it must contain all contents of the class and they must all be defined.

So you need to declare the class as abstract which means that the class cannot be instantiated. But just because a class is abstract, doesn't mean it *must* implement only abstract methods. For example, you can have a static method in an abstract class because calling a static method belongs to the *class* rather than an *object* or *instance* of the class.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class can have methods abstracts and non abstract. For exemple,

```
public abstract class Employee {
    ...

    //this method would be implemented in those classes that extends from Employee. 
    public abstract void calculateSalary(); 

    public Employee addEmployee() {
         //Method body
    }
```

But if you declare an abstract method in a non abstract class this has to be converted itself into am abstract one.

On the other hand abstract methods will be implemented in the inherited classes of an abstract parent class. So you would be doing this implementation in a generic class.

I hope this would helps.